# BREAK using Regex in JAVA

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm new to using Regex
I want to get macapp value in url just get number 12 to String how do that ?

```
String url = "stackoverflow.com/questions/ask:macapp=12";

Pattern pattern = ;// ?

Matcher matcher =;// ?


if(matcher.find()) 
{
    //result = only 12
}

THX for your TIME
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what your question is. Do you want to extract a number that appears at the end of a string? Or a number that appears after the word `macapp=`? What does break have to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*:macapp=(\\d+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
  int n = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
  ...
}
```

Comment: thx man please make this pattern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58509600/finding-the-after-matching-string-in-java