# Finding the after matching String in java

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a problem with pattern. I need to get value(number and text) after `macapp=` and after `locapp=` between 2 words is `&` how do this

```java
String temp  = "http://sedaword.com/app/fr/main.php?macapp=admin22&locapp=30.330345,59.607153";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*?macapp=(.+)$&"); //this my problem

Matcher m = p.matcher(temp);

if (m.find()) {

    String macapp = String.valueOf(m.group(1)); //output   admin22
    String locapp= String.valueOf(m.group(2));//output 30.330345,59.607153
}
```

Comment: I think the trick is a *reluctant quantifier*, it will only take up to the first ampersand: `(.+?)&`. And leave out the `$`, I think it causes trouble there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try like this:

```
String temp  = "http://sedaword.com/app/fr/main.php?macapp=admin22&locapp=30.330345,59.607153";
String[] resultArray = temp.split("macapp=")[1].split("&locapp=");
System.out.println(resultArray[0]); //admin22
System.out.println(resultArray[1]); //30.330345,59.607153
```

Answer (score 1):

You can correct your regular expression in the following way:

```java
String url  = "http://sedaword.com/app/fr/main.php?macapp=admin22&locapp=30.330345,59.607153";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*\\?macapp=(.+)&locapp=(.+)$");

Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
if (m.find()) {
  String macapp = m.group(1);
  String locapp = m.group(2);
}
```

But I would suggest you to use some library for this purpose.
See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

Another more generic option is to make use of Java 8's streams and collect all the key value pairs in a map.

```
String url = "http://sedaword.com/app/fr/main.php?macapp=admin22&locapp=30.330345,59.607153";
url = url.substring( url.indexOf( "main.php" ) + "main.php".length() + 1 ); // substring after main.php

Map<String,String> map = Arrays.stream( url.split( "&" ) ) // split on &
         .map( str -> str.split( "=" ) ) // split on =
         .collect( Collectors.toMap( arr -> arr[ 0 ], arr2 -> arr2[ 1 ] ) ); // collect to map

for ( Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet() ) {
    System.out.println( String.format( "Key=%s, value=%s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() ) );
}
```

output is

```
Key=locapp, value=30.330345,59.607153
Key=macapp, value=admin22
```